# How does a C++ compiler handle offsets with multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++

Bear with me as I try to articulate my issue. I guess what I'm trying to understand is given something like this:

```
class Base1 { public: int value { 5 }; };
class Base2 { /* fields */ };

class Derived1 : public Base1 { ... };
class Derived2 : public Base2, public Derived1 { ... };
```

how does the compiler resolve the memory offsets for code like this?

```
void base1_action(Base1 *instance) { 
    cout << instance->value << endl;
}

void change_base(Base2* instance) {
    base1_action(reinterpret_cast<Base1*>(instance));
}

int main() {
    Base2* instance = new Derived2;
    change_base(instance);
}
```

That is, if in `main` the actual object instance is of type `Derived2`, when the base change happens in `change_base` from `Base2` to `Base1`, how is the compiler able to know how to re-compute the offsets for the object so that when `base1_action` is called, it's getting a pointer to the correct offset for `Base1`?

In other words, when there is multiple inheritance, how is the compiler able to compute the offsets from one base class to another base class (instead of the easier question of computing a base class offset from a known derived class)?

Hopefully my question is somewhat clear - thank you!

Comment: The given example code won't compile. Please provide code that compiles.

Comment: Elven magic and an implementation defined taco.

Comment: Edited, should compile now.

Comment: Note that the `reinterpret_cast` here is UB.

Comment: Any way it wants. But a good description of one way is at http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html.

Comment: If you're interested in the memory layout of things then you can do worse than reading Lippman's "Inside the C++ Object Model".

Comment: @Cheers: I'll get a copy, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`base1_action(reinterpret_cast<Base1*>(instance));`

"how is the compiler able to know how to re-compute the offsets for the object"

It doesn't. You are using `reinterpret_cast`, which means something like "here are bits of one type, now treat it as if it were bits of that other type". There is no offset calculation involved here. In other words: This is a bug in the code.

If you were to write `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` instead the compiler would indeed need to calculate offsets. Since it knows both types and the memory layout of the types it can easily add or subtract the correct offset. If you were to hide the types for example by assigning the pointers to `void *` before the `static_cast` it would fail to apply the correct offset calculation.

Comment: Ah, so what I'm trying to do (sideways cast) really IS impossible for the compiler to determine then. Is that right?

Comment: @sircodesalot I don't know what sideways cast means. If you use the right types with the right cast the compiler will do the right thing. If you don't you will most likely not get the correct behavior.

Comment: In other words, for some type that implements two bases, to cast directly from one base directly to another - this is disallowed?

Comment: @sircodesalot `reinterpret_cast` will ignore offsets and just copy the bits. That is kind of casting, but it doesn't do the right thing. `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` will refuse to work because there is no relationship between the bases you are showing. If one base were to inherit from another it would work. If you try to cast between unrelated types the "safe" casts will refuse.

Comment: Got it, that answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @nwp: cross-cast **is** possible with `dynamic_cast`, though not with `static_cast`. It just needs the existence of some virtuals (bases or functions) in the source *and* target class.

Answer (score 0):

It think, GCC/MinGW will do it this way:

```
class Base1 { public: int value { 5 }; }
class Base2 { /* fields */ }
class Derived1 : public Base1 { ... }
class Derived2 : public Base2, public Derived1 { ... }


Derived2:
    Base2 fields
    Derived1:
        Base1 fields
        Derived1 fields
    Derived2 fields
```

Comment: I don't know what else I can add to my answer. If OP know where fields are located, it should be obvious to him how to calculate offset.

Comment: If you look at the function signatures it should be clearer what I'm asking, I think.